# Работа форм сайта, скачанного с тильды

Tags: формы, tilda

Есть сайт, скачен экспортом с тильды.
Мне нужно подключить формы к crm, но при отправке форм выдаёт ошибку, что нужно поменять домен в настройках. Я могу решить эту проблему через файлы? Я пробовал менять домен в robots, htaccess, site map, но ничего не происходит.

Comment: Может нужно поменять домен на стороне CRM?

Comment: Нет, дело не в crm